# Div is not showing up even if i make visible: true in knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-mvc

The below Div is not showing up even if i make visible: true

```
        <div id="filterPart" data-bind="visible:$root.shouldShowDropDown" > 
        <section class="individual t-padding1 t-border">
            <g:render template="/admin/adminMessageDropDownMenu"/>
        </section>
        </div>
```

I am setting the value as true in .js file as below

```
self.shouldShowDropDown(true);
```

but still Div is not becoming visible.I think i should right something like

```
<div id="filterPart" data-bind="visible:$root.shouldShowDropDown,valueUpdate:[]" >
```

valueUpdate in data-bind to reflect the value(i mean to make visible)? I am not getting exactly what i need to write....

Comment: Why are you using the `$root` modifier here? Are you in the context of a child observable? `valueUpdate` is used for input elements, to change when the observable is updated while typing, so it's not used like you're guessing.

Comment: Show code for you view model because what you have should work. There's something else going on that we aren't seeing. Also, check your console for error messages.

Comment: There are many, many reasons why this could fail:
1. Your CSS has a rule overriding the behavior by using !important
2. You have binding errors
3. The bindings have never been applied
4. `self` is not the root level of the viewmodel that's bound to this part of the UI
5. The div is actually visible but all its contents are hidden via other JS/CSS
6. And many, many more. To be more specific, we need more code, and you should also use something like the element inspector to see what CSS is applied to the div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi friends this was happening due to code crash as the code was not executing fully. There was  a network problem, POST request was getting failed so it was not retrieving any data from database so the application was not running properly